# How to ensure I control France after its capitulation?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I was playing the Netherlands, took over part of China, Portugues, and Spain.

After defeating Spain I attacked France from North and south and invaded it very fast almost completely myself.

At some point, France capitulated. The problem is that instead of taking its territories to myself (looking to get its dockyards to build the fleet and assault England), France felt under Germany and created a Vichy France...

As a result... I got nothing. Curious why? How can I ensure that I get at least a part of France's territory till the war is over?

This all is with the plan to get "Putting the Raid on the Medway to Shame" achievement

P.S. If it helps, before attacking Spain I had my own faction with DEI and Venezuela. While in war with Spain, Japan attacked DEI and as a result, when I attacked France *I believe* I was in this huge conflict when:

- Japan is in a defensive war against the Soviet Union.
- Japan is in an offensive war against the UK, France, myself, DEI and many other countries

Answer (score 1):

As the unnamed commenter said:

- A country holding the most victory points at the time of surrender will capitulate the country.
- If Paris is occumpied by Germany a custom surrender event is triggered for France.